# Is it possible to solve such an unlinear matrix equation?

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix equation of the form:
$Sx=x^TKxp$, while $
    S = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & a & a \\
    b & 0 & b \\
    c & c & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$, $a$ and $b$ are real, known numbers, $K = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$, $p = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $x = \begin{pmatrix}
    r \\
    s \\
    t
\end{pmatrix}$ with $r$, $s$ and $t$ as the unknows.
Is it possible to solve this equation system analytically or only numerically? How can a approach be?

Comment: You know $x$ has the form $\lambda S^{-1}p$ for some scalar $\lambda$. Substitute this into $S x = (x^T K x)p$, you get a equation in $\lambda$....

Comment: Is $c$ also given? If $c=0$, then $x^TKx=0$ necessarily and $S$ doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: Thanks a lot to achille hui and amsmath: The substitution with $\lambda$ was a great idea and I was able to solve the equation. Also sorry I forgot to mention, that $a$, $b$ and also $c$ are real, known numbers (and (a,b,c) > 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=x^TKx=rs+st+tr$ (1).

$Sx=up$ is then a straightforward equation which gives $r,s,t$ in terms of $u$.

Substitute into (1) and you have a quadratic equation for $u$.

Comment: I think also because the r.h.s has just this one entry one can get a necessary condition for solvability in terms of what (a,b,c) is, if I didn't do a mistake at  the calculation actually one need $\begin{pmatrix} -c & a-c & a \\ -b & a& a-b \\ b -c & -c & b\end{pmatrix} x = 0$.